# Conexión remota a Sql Server 2017 Con varias instancias

Tags: sql-server

Al intentar conectarme al Sql Server 2017, de un servidor con varias instancias me sale esté error, teniendo en cuenta que me permite conectar a la instancia local, pero no a las que he agregado, no creo que sea por falta de configuración seguí todos los pasos al pie de la letra

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to NUTIBARA\DESARROLLO.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se
>   establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el
>   servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la
>   instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir
>   conexiones remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se
>   pudo abrir una conexión con SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:
>   1326)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=1326&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> Error de inicio de sesión: nombre de usuario desconocido o contraseña
>   incorrecta
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Comment: Estás conectándote desde el mismo equipo o desde otro? con el Management Studio? si no, ¿cuál es la cadena de conexión?

Comment: Cuando usas instancias diferentes a la default, son Instancias Nombradas y usan un puerto aleatorio diferente al 1433. Por lo tanto, tienes que configurar el rango de puertos que MSSQL va a usar y abrirlo en el firewall.

Answer (score 1):

- Cerciorate de que el firewall no esté bloqueando el puerto del SQL SERVER
- Cerciorate de que esté habilitado el protocolo TCP/IP de la instancia
- Verifica que este habilitado el server para conexiones remotas

Una vez que hayas verificado lo anterior compartenos si te sirvió algunas de éstas soluciones

Comment: Al parecer era que el Firewall estaba bloqueando la conexión a los demás puertos de conexión de esas instancias, por eso sólo conectaba a la local del servidor, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me he topado con algunas causas de este error. Ojala alguna te sirva de guía.

Puede ser el protocolo en la instancia que estas conectando este deshabilitado en el Configuration Manager.

El servicio SQL Browser puede estar apagado por lo que no detecta la segunda instancia usando el nombre.

No esta detectando el puerto por el que escucha la segunda instancia. Esto se puede solucionar especificando el puerto después del nombre del servidor o configurando un Alias. Si hay una capa de seguridad de red hay que validar que no haya una regla que bloquee ese puerto.